# Java Recursion output

Tags: java, recursion

May I know why the output is `2 1 0` for this instead of `2`

```
public class recur {
  public static void count(int index) {

    if(index < 2) {
      count(index+1);
    }
    System.out.println(index);      
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    recur.count(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: public class recur
{
 public static void count(int index)
 {
  
  if(index<2)
  {
   count(index+1);
  }
  System.out.println(2);
   
 }
 
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  recur.count(0);
 }
}  output now 2 2 2

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the flow works:

1. `index == 0`, calls `count(1)`
2. `index == 1`, calls `count(2)`
3. `index == 2`; prints 2 AND this iteration of `count()` returns to step #2, and continues to the next step in `count()`, which is `System.out.println(i)`, which prints 1
4. same as step #3, return from `count` and continue with `System.out.println(i)`. At this point, value of `i` is 0

Answer (score 0):

Because your count method calls itself.  When you call count(0) it hits the if block and calls count(1).  That also enters the if block and calls count(2).  2 is not < 2 so it doesn't enter the if block and prints "2", then exits.  At that point you are back where you called count(1), so it exits the if block and prints 1, then exits that method invocation.  Now you are back where you started in the original method call to count(0).  This too leaves the if block and prints 0, then exits and we return to the main method.

Comment: why is it going back to count(1) instead of returning back to main method ?

Comment: You started off in main, which calls count(0), which calls count(1), which calls count(2).  As each method invocation completes, execution continues in the method invocation that called it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `index < 2`, the `count()` method recurses on itself, passing `count+1` in the recursive call. After the recursive call to `count(index+1)` returns, execution continues with the call to `System.out.println()` for the current value of `index`. This occurs *after* the recursive call has completed (and has generated its own output).

The key point is that making a recursive call does not stop execution of the remainder of the method; it just defers it until the recursive call returns.